# Microsoft Bot Framework throws error on sending landscape or rectangle image as media

Tags: .net, botframework, telegram-bot

C# Microsoft chatbot over telegram channel will throw error on channel when uploading image as image not file.
if the image is landscape or rectangle will not work.

Channel Error: Sequence contains no matching element

the error is not received by the bot.
connected the channel to local bot but the data is not received.

Comment: Per the [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/2652) issue, i'm not able to reproduce this. Try ensuring BF SDK and telegram are up to newest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in microsofts telegram out of the box uploading system, this was fixed from microsoft

https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/2652#event-2742246218